Isomorphism of Endomorphism Ring of Vector Space and Semisimple Elements
Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and $V$ a (not necessarily finite-dimensional) vector space over $k$. Let $\sigma: \text{End}(V) \to \text{End}(V)$ be a ring isomorphism (not necessarily $k$-algebra isomorphism).
Clearly, $\sigma$ maps nilpotent endomorphisms to nilpotent endomorphisms. Does $\sigma$ also map semisimple endomorphisms to semisimple endomorphisms?
Here, an endomorphism $\Phi \in \text{End}(V)$ is semisimple if $\Phi$ has over an algebraic closure $\bar k$ of $k$ a basis of eigenvectors, i.e. is diagonalizable over $\bar k$.
If this was true then $\sigma$ would map a Jordan-Chevalley decomposition $\Phi = \Phi_s + \Phi_n$ of some endomorphism $\Phi\in \text{End}(V)$ to a Jordan-Chevalley decomposition.
I don't think that this is true in general since I don't see any relation between the characteristic polynomials of $\sigma \Phi$ and $\Phi$ for example (if $V$ was finite-dimensional and $\sigma$ is no $k$-algebra isomorphism). However, I have no counterexample.
